# Flask POST request and javascript

Tags: flask

Is it possible to POST data with flask_sqlalchemy and prevent a page reload?

I have a webpage with a form. The form only appears after a function, activated by an onclick event, is run. I want my user to be able to submit information using the form, and see the form only empty and the rest of the page remain unchanged.

I have already tried `return '', 204` but this does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javascript or jQuery:

**Javascript example**:

```js
function resetFormPause() {
        myVar = setTimeout(resetForm, 250);
    }

    function resetForm() {
        document.getElementById('form').reset();
    }
```

Add `onclick='resetFormPause()'` to your submit button and use `<form id='form'>`.

We use `setTimeout()` to allow the data to be sent. If we merely add the `resetForm()` function, we will delete the data that we want to send. If we have small text to send, 250ms is plenty of time. If we have larger data, then we use the same idea, but we have to (a) allow more time, or (b) use an event to trigger the execution of `resetForm()`.